# Is there a way to jump back and forth between the header and the source file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, navigation

If I'm in the header, I'd like to switch to the source, and vice versa. Something like the XCode keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Cmd + up arrow (I'm on Mac).

Thanks!

Comment: Java don't use headers, what are you trying to see/do?

Comment: Android apps can definitely have C++ modules, and Android Studio does handle C++ and headers just fine. I just can't find a shortcut to switch from header to source and vice versa.

Comment: I didn't say that Android Studio can't support C++ modules. Perhaps you didn't mention that you're are using the NDK and trying to navigate C++ files. In Android Studio any code and includes are tabs. Those tabs are not related, so there's no direct switch between C++ source and the correspondant header. Instead that you can navigate tabs back and forward, but you will have to search the keys by yourself because I'm on Linux right now (I use ALT+left or rig,ht arrow). The place to look is Settings->Keymap->Window->Editor tabs (be aware that splitted tabs shortcuts are not defined by default).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Not quite the same thing, but could come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It's in the menu:

Navigate > Header/Source.

You can find and edit the key mapping as needed.

Thanks for the tip @CodeMole!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your keymap.  I have Visual Studio keymaps selected.  To check your keymap:

- Android Studio => Settings => Keymap
- Refer to the dropdown
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x6xr.png)
- If you also have Visual Studio selected, then you can toggle between source and header file using the following key combinations:
- CTRL/K => CTRL/O (Hold down the CTRL button, then press K, then O)

Unfortunately, I don't see XCode as a keymap selection, but you might try some of the others.  They may be similar?